# MySQL transactions in more queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, transactions

I am learning MySQL transactions and now I am making a PHP aplication. I understood, that this should work:

```
$mysqli->query('START TRANSACTION; INSERT INTO sada (jmeno) VALUES ('.$name.'); COMMIT;');
```

That's great, but it isn't, what I wont. Can I use something like this?

```
$mysqli->query('START TRANSACTION;');
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO sada (jmeno) VALUES ('.$i.')');
}
$mysqli->query('COMMIT;');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$mysqli->autocommit(false);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO sada (jmeno) VALUES ('.$i.')');
}

$mysqli->commit();
$mysqli->autocommit(true);
```

Check the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) for additional info